# Conditionally Add External CSS/Javascript Links

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, asp.net-4.0

I need to add links to the header of an ASPX page based on a server-side function being called from `Page_Load()` of the Master Page. The entire site is using the same Master Page.

What's the best way to do this?

An `<asp:Literal>` control in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe too late, but the approach below has the advantage, that the same script is never added twice.

```
public static void RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page page, string name, string url)
{
    Type cstype = page.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the include script exists already.
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(cstype, name))
    {
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(cstype, name, page.ResolveClientUrl(url));
    }
}
```

Come in handy, if you add external javascript files from different user controls on a need basis.

Comment: Can this be used to add links to external JavaScript files? I've only ever used it to add raw JS code.

Comment: Yes, it can. RegisterClientScriptInclude is the key.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that:

1. In your `Page_Load` method, access the header of your master page programmatically like:

   ```
   HtmlGenericControl style = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
   style.Attributes.Add("href", "path-to-your-style");
   style.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
   style.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
   this.Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, style);
   ```
2. Second way is to put `runat='server'` attribute on your conditional styles in head, and in your `Page_Load` method, turn their **visibility** on or off:

   ```
   <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='path-to-css-file' 
   runat='server' id='cssFile' />
   ```

   then in your `Page_Load` you have:

   ```
   if (conditionIsNotMet)
   {
       cssFile.Visible = false;
   }
   ```

Comment: (1) snazzy, seems much cleaner than a Literal

Answer (score 1):

I've had success doing things like this in the past.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dhxStyle"] %>" />
```